# Trouble with divide 2 values from different tables

Tags: mysql, retention

I am writing a request to build a chart of the 7th day retention by day cohorts. I have dataset like:

```
user_id, event_name, datetime
1, install, 20 jan 2018 10:00:00
1, activity, 20 jan 2018 11:00:00
2, install, 20 feb 2018 12:00:00
2, activity, 22 feb 2018 13:00:00
```

I built two tables in phpmyadmin where I grouped user_id by datetime and with condition event_name = 'activate' in first and 'install' in second. After tried divide COUNT(user_id) from these 2 tables in third table.

(First table - result_install):

```
INSERT INTO result_install 
SELECT COUNT(user_id), datetime 
FROM customers 
WHERE event_name = 'install' 
GROUP BY datetime ORDER BY datetime;
```

(Second table - result_activate):

```
INSERT INTO result_activate 
SELECT COUNT(user_id), datetime 
FROM customers 
WHERE event_name = 'activate' and datetime = '2018-01-26';
```

(Third table - result):

```
INSERT INTO result(retention_rate, date_retention) 
SELECT result_activate.count_activate / result_install.count_install AS retention_rate, date_install 
FROM result_install;
```

I expect the output retention_rate like 11/25

Comment: Off topic:  You should be using `INSERT INTO table (<columns>) SELECT ...`  syntax,,  Your current INSERT's are prone to syntax/data errors if the column order changes or columns are added/removed.in one of the tables or both

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you explain me where is my error? I kind of wrote in the same way, didn't it?

Comment: only the last one yes..